# Redirecting a webpage to new URL when old server is shut down

Tags: html

i want to redirect a webpage to new URL as it has been migrated to new server. The old server is being shutdown. So is there any way through which a user using old URL could be redirected to new one after server shutdown?

Comment: Are the URLs changing? Or just the server?

Answer (score 1):

*A* server, any server, will have to serve that URL. You will have to set up a web server that responds to requests for that URL, point the DNS entry at that server and then configure it to redirect to a different URL. That server could be on the same physical machine as the new site.